# How to decrease list height in v-select vuetify3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, v-select, vuetifyjs3

I can't decrease list height... list height becomes full screen height

[image]

I tried a lot of ways, but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is weird, as per default, the (max-)height is set to 310px (see [source](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.tsx#L246)).

But you can change the height by passing a configuration object to the underlying `v-menu` through the [`:menu-props`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) prop. You have to adjust the [`:max-height`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-max-height):

```html
<v-select
  :menu-props="{
    'max-height': 310
   }"
/>
```

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed} = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const items = Array.from({length: 100}, (_,i) => `Options ${i+1}`)
    const maxHeightNumber = ref(0)
    const maxHeight = computed(() => maxHeightNumber.value  > 0 ? maxHeightNumber.value + 'px' : 'auto')
    
    return { items, maxHeight, maxHeightNumber}
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <div>
      <v-select
        :items="items"
        label="Options Options Options"
        :menu-props="{
          'max-height': maxHeight
        }"
      />
      </div><div>
      <v-text-field :label="'max height (' + maxHeight + ')'" type="number" step="100" v-model="maxHeightNumber"></v-text-field>
      </div>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, just height in menu-props helped me instead of max-height :)